# Magento extensions for comparins config values

Tags: magento

is there magento extension that can be used for comparing config values that are set on development and staging site?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [TechDivision_SystemConfigDiff](https://github.com/techdivision/TechDivision_SystemConfigDiff). Diffs of system configuration, cms blocks and cms pages are supported.